# How can I avoid text-decoration on icons when using font-awesome within a link?

Tags: css, font-awesome

I've just started using FontAwesome, so far so good. One question though, when I use it with an anchor tag and it has `text-decoration:none`, and on hover `text-decoration:underline`. When I hover the link, the icon gets the underline effect, too…how do I get only the link to be underlined, not the icon?

I tried to placing it outside the anchor tag, but it doesn't get the color I assigned to the link

Sample code:

```
<style>
  a{color:red;text-decoration:none;}
  a:hover{text-decoration:underline;}
</style>

<a href="#"><span class="fa fa-camera-retro"> </span>This's a test</a>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I popped your exact code into JSFiddle and noticed that the camera icon itself wasn't being underlined completely, but the space between the icon and the text was.

So, if that's what you're experiencing, you can simply **add a bit of padding after the icon**, that way there's no whitespace to underline.

```css
a {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.fa {
  padding-right: 5px;
}
a:hover .fa {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<a href="#"><span class="fa fa-camera-retro"></span>This is a test</a>
```

The last item in the CSS was merely to show that no underline effect was happening on hover by changing the icon's color to show formatting wasn't being applied from other items. Notice there's no space after the `span` tag, instead the space is created by the 5px padding applied to anything with the `.fa` class.

I tested this in both a very recent version of Firefox, and IE9 because those are what's on my work machine.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, and found that the `fa` class defines an `inline-block` display mode. If I forced the `display` to `inline` inside a link, then everything was fine.

```
a > .fa {
  display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a style for the `a:hover span.fa` selector:

```
<style>
  a {
    color: red;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  a:hover span.fa {
    text-decoration: none;
  }
</style>

<a href="#"><span class="fa fa-camera-retro"></span> This is a test</a>
```

Comment: could you give sample codes regarding the FYI? I used the exact code from fontawesome site, but instead of <i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i> (it italic the icon), i change the <i part to a <span class="fa fa-camera-retro"></span>

Comment: I was totally wrong about my FYI and deleted it, sorry. I got it backwards... Just like you had, 'fa' is correct for 4.x; sorry for any confusion

Answer (score 0):

Put your `<span>` outside of the `<a>` so its not affected by your hover...

```
<span class="fa fa-camera-retro"></span><a href="#">This is a test</a>
```

Comment: Generally folks like the icon to be part of the link, especially for mobile.